# Why is Lat/Lng always 0/0 when GPS is turned off?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to simply get the Lat/Lng of the device once in order to run a search query for that location.  Given that, I don't need to keep asking for the location, I just need an accurate location (so not an old stored location) at the time the activity is created.

My problem is that when GPS is off, the Lat/Lng is always 0/0...so the Provider/Network location service obviously isn't working for some reason.  When GPS is on...it works great and I get a Lat/Lng.

Here is my Activity:

```
package com.app.abc123;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Search_results extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView mWebView;
private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
String provider;
LocationManager lm;
android.location.Location l;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String intentLat = intent.getStringExtra("LAT");
    String intentLng = intent.getStringExtra("LNG");
    String intentQuery = intent.getStringExtra("QUERY");

    setTitle(intentQuery);

    if ((Double.valueOf(intentLat) == 0) || (Double.valueOf(intentLng) == 0)) {
        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);
        l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l != null) {
            intentLat = String.valueOf(l.getLatitude());
            intentLng = String.valueOf(l.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_search_results);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://abc123.azurewebsites.net/search.php?lat=" + intentLat + "&lng=" + intentLng + "&query=" + intentQuery);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        ...
        Web view stuff
        ...

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_results, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: refresh_page();");
            return true;
        default:
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
            return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // finish() is called in super: we only override this method to be able to override the transition
    super.onBackPressed();

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
}
```

}

And yes, I do have the proper permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBestProvider` just says that it [Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). It doesn't necessarily mean that the provider has a fix.

The [location strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate) document has a good section about getting the best estimate of current position.

```
Location lastGpsLocation = null;
Location lastNetworkLocation = null;
List<String> enabledLocationProviders = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);

if (enabledLocationProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    lastGpsLocation = mLocationManager
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} else if (enabledLocationProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    lastNetworkLocation = mLocationManager
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

Then compare the two using `isBetterLocation` from the [location strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate) doc.